# PHP Redirect 301 - .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, header, redirect

I would like to redirect users from one old page to a new page usinh PHP Redirect Code. I found this but now the everything is redirecting to the new page and just would like to hape to some specific page.
This is the code im using that it´s not working:

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com"); 
?>
```

Is there any option to specify just a sub-url to a new url?

**EDIT**

I already tried using .htaccess but it´s not working there. So i decided to use this way. Anyway, is it possible even like this? by the way, i tried two codes using .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^stand/index.php(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/stand-carros-usados$1 [R=301,L]`
```

and

```
Redirect 301 stand/index.php(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/stand-carros-usados
```

but none of them really worked.

Comment: Where did you write that code?

Comment: can't you use .htaccess ?

Comment: If something is solved, post an answer and/or make one as accepted. Don't update the question with "Solved!"

Comment: thanks deceze. im learning

Comment: `RewriteRule ^stand/index.php(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/stand-carros-usados$1 [R=301,L]` - it´s working this one. Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if mod-rewrite is active or not. In your Apache configurations, there should be an uncommented statement like `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod-rewrite.so`. If it is commented, uncomment it and restart the server. After that, put the following inside the `stand` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/stand-carros-usados$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```